# Exposing Simulation-only behavior in Chisel3

Tags: chisel

I want to expose certain signals only during simulation (for performance monitoring purposes, etc...) that can be used during the debug process for various purposes. I *could*  use the `dontTouch` annotation to ensure that the counter, which is necessarily eliminated by DCE, is preserved in simulation and visible in the final waveform, but this would mean that the component would also be preserved during synthesis.

Chisel3 generates `'ifndef SYNTHESIS` verilog macros for cases of `VerificationStatement`(e.g. `$printf`, `$stop`, ...). Is there a way for a user to more generally use the `'ifndef SYNTHESIS` macro within their designs or would I need to write my own FIRRTL/CIRCT annotations/passes to provide this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative approach would be to probe the internals of the design from the testbench.  This uses a new feature of Chisel 6 (`BoringUtils.tapAndRead`) to create cross-module references.

Here's a small example:

```scala
//> using scala "2.13.10"
//> using repository "https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
//> using lib "org.chipsalliance::chisel::6.0.0-M1+3-35860474-SNAPSHOT"
//> using plugin "org.chipsalliance:::chisel-plugin::6.0.0-M1+3-35860474-SNAPSHOT"
//> using options "-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-language:reflectiveCalls", "-feature", "-Xcheckinit", "-Ywarn-dead-code", "-Ywarn-unused", "-Ymacro-annotations"

import chisel3._
import chisel3.util.experimental.BoringUtils
import circt.stage.ChiselStage

class Bar extends RawModule {
  val b = WireInit(Bool(), DontCare)
  dontTouch(b)
}

class Foo extends RawModule {
  val bar = Module(new Bar)

  val a = WireInit(Bool(), BoringUtils.tapAndRead(bar.b))
  dontTouch(a)
}

object Main extends App {
  println(ChiselStage.emitSystemVerilog(new Foo))
}
```

Running this (`scala-cli Foo.scala`) produces the following Verilog:

```
module Bar();   
  wire b = 1'h0;        
endmodule

module Foo();   
  wire a = Foo.bar.b;   
  Bar bar ();   
endmodule
```

You could also do this by creating a "debug module" inside `Bar` with all the signals you want.  This module can then be excluded from synthesis.  There is no great mechanism to exclude a module from synthesis (either via emitting it as a Verilog `bind` to a specific bind file or with `ifdef`s).  Support for instantiating a module via a `bind` is expected soon-ish.

Comment: Thank you. For the time being, and because of my dependence on tools that do not support some of the more modern Chisel versions, I'm going with a FIRRTL transform.

Answer (score 1):

In [chiseltest](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chiseltest) we provide a simple `expose` feature that allows you to make arbitrary signals from your design available as outputs in your toplevel. If you want to use this only for simulation, the trick is to make a simulation toplevel module that just wraps your design under test and adds all necessary `expose` statements. Have a look at this [small example](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chiseltest/blob/8902fe1093458ea21afebbac7507f8fbde80ead1/src/test/scala/chiseltest/experimental/tests/ObserveExposeTest.scala).